# I have a problem positioning my footer div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to position my footer to the center, but it keeps sticking to left
[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV2fU.png)

This is my code (core.blade.php):

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="row align-self-end">
        <p>Copyright 2021 Me. All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.footer {
    background-color: #E21B4D;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: make sure it is the child of `body` element. from the proof it seems like it's within the right side section

Comment: How looks the parent of class="footer"?
That behavior depends on how it is structured your HTML and what styles did you set on CSS. Would be more easy to help you if share more context code

Comment: I cant the reproduce the issue with the code you have provided. Please add a [repro]

Answer (score 0):

try this bottom property

```
.footer {
          background-color: #E21B4D;
          padding: 10px;
          justify-content: center;
          color: white;
          display: flex;
          align-items:center;
          bottom: 0;
        }
```

Look at this link

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp